# Accessing Uploaded Sharepoint File from SPItemEventProperties Using C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

You'll have to forgive my ignorance with regards to deploying this code. I have written some code to modify an event reciever. I have set up a development environment for sharepoint. The development environment is now running fine without any issues. The following code is that which I would like to test.

```
private void commentscheck(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {

        bool commentsorrevisions = false;


        if (!properties.AfterUrl.EndsWith("docx"))
        {
            commentsorrevisions = WordCommentsChecker(fileobject);
        }
        elif (!properties.AfterUrl.EndsWith("xlsx"))
        {
            commentsorrevisions = ExcelCommentsChecker(fileobject);
        }

        else:
            return true;



private static bool WordCommentsChecker(string filename)
    {
        bool outcome = false;
        Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
        Word.Document document = wordApp.Documents.Open(filename);
        int commentscount = document.Comments.Count;
        int revisionscount = document.Revisions.Count;
        if (commentscount != 0 || revisionscount != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("comments");
            document.ActiveWindow.Close();
            wordApp.Application.Quit(-1);
            outcome = true;
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No Comments.");
            document.ActiveWindow.Close();
            wordApp.Application.Quit(-1);
            outcome = false;
        }

        return outcome;
    }
```

However how would I go about actually testing this code and event reciever on my development sharepoint environment.

Thanks,

Freddie

Comment: The url with the format to open the document should be properties.AfterUrl

Comment: How exactly would I load and open that?